# What is the equivalent of LIKE with wildcard the end 'abc%' using greater/less than operators?

Tags: postgresql, sql-standard

I just found out that some specific patterns when used with LIKE text operator uses BTREE indexes to speed up queries, such as:

- 'abc123' (text with no wildcard)
- 'abc%' (text with only one wildcard in the end)

What is the equivalent of LIKE text operator using a pattern with only one wildcard `'%'` present in the pattern's end (such as `"a_column" LIKE 'abc%'`) using just greater/less/equal than operators?

My interest is achieving this in PostgreSQL, but this may be an SQL standard question.

Comment: Afaik you can’t use Wildcards with GT-/LT-Operators.

Comment: Yes, I know that... my point here is if a LIKE with wildcard pattern is leveraging BTREE indexes it must be converted into a GT/LT/EQ operation... so how is that done? what is it equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no way to replace a wildcard search with `>=` and `<` operations. Consider this example:

```
SELECT 'abcd' LIKE 'abc%' COLLATE "cs_CZ.utf8",
       'abch' LIKE 'abc%' COLLATE "cs_CZ.utf8";

 ?column? │ ?column? 
══════════╪══════════
 t        │ t

SELECT 'abcd' >= 'abc' COLLATE "cs_CZ.utf8" AND
       'abcd' < 'abd' COLLATE "cs_CZ.utf8",
       'abch' >= 'abc' COLLATE "cs_CZ.utf8" AND
       'abch' < 'abd' COLLATE "cs_CZ.utf8";

 ?column? │ ?column? 
══════════╪══════════
 t        │ f
(1 row)
```

So in Czech there is no way to replace `LIKE 'abc%'` with the regular inequality operators.

The only collation where this always works is the binary collation `C` (or `POSIX`).  Alternatively, you can use the inequality operators `~>=~` and `~<~`, which compare strings character by character.

Why don't you use the proper solution and create an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tab (a_column text_pattern_ops);
```

This index can speed up both of your `LIKE` expressions, and there is no need to rewrite the query.

Comment: I confess I have to take a look on text_pattern_ops index and collations to better understand your answer.

Maybe I haven't expressed myself properly and I shoudl have asked it differently. Actually my inital plan was to store LIKE patterns in a column and use it to filter another table using a JOIN operation. What I found out is that LIKE didn't used the index but >= and < did and boom, that's how my question was born.

Comment: There could be two approaches from the top of my head: a trigram index or the string prefix operator `^@` with an SPGiST index. Perhaps you should ask another question for that.

Comment: In my current scenario I don't want to create SPGiST indexes as they tend to get really big in contrast to a btree. As I'm not using any non ASCII characters on the text column I learned from your answer that's easier to use the C collation to achieve the result I need. Thank's!

Answer (score -1):

`"a_column" >= 'abc' AND "a_column" < 'abd'` should be equivalent to `"a_column" LIKE 'abc%'` - `'abc'` will match because it is equal to the search term and any string starting with `abc` will be greater than it but less than `abd`.

This is assuming your collation is set such that you'll get a binary comparison, you will need some extra thinking to make things work as desired with case-insensitive or accent-insensitive comparisons.

Comment: But there are cases, e.g. where `WHERE a_column LIKE Ha%` is not equivalent to `WHERE a_column >= 'Ha' AND a_column < 'Hb'` as shown in this question: [Relationships between like matching and comparison](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316446/relationships-between-like-matching-and-comparison/316460#316460) Still,  the condition `WHERE a_column >= 'Ha' AND a_column < 'Hb'`  can be used in a LIKE query, as it is a superset of the LIKE condition, so it can be used to retrieve (a superset of) the matching rows with an index+partial scan and then apply the LIKE filter.

Comment: That is only true for certain collations...